# Can time-travel and fail-safe apply for an object at the same time?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can time-travel and fail-safe apply for an object at the same time? I understand fail-safe period of 7 days starts only after time-travel period ends for applicable object. However, as per Snowflake University mindtickle assessment, the Fail-Safe is available for tables that have time-travel. Please explain.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6jN5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *[Check all true statements about Fail-safe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6jN5.png)*:
>
> …
>
> `[ ]` *"[Fail-safe is not available for tables that have Time Travel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6jN5.png)"*

The (curveball) choice in context is referring to `Time Travel` and `Fail-safe` as available features to any permanent table, not as it's currently-used areas of storage.

It reads better when phrased as:

> "*Fail-safe feature is not available for tables that have Time Travel features*"

Since the question's context is about the fail-safe feature, [which only apply to permanent tables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-cdp-storage-costs.html), the statement is **false**.

Answer (score 0):

For a table, time-travel, as well as failsafe both, are applicable.

There is no direct connection between time-travel and failsafe, though they are part of the continuous data protection strategy. A few key differences

1. time-travel can be configured, by default 1 day and can range from 0 to 90 days (7 days for the standard edition and up to 90 days for enterprise and above).
2. Failsafe is not configurable and defaults to 7 days.
3. To recover data from failed safe, you need to contact snowflake support.
4. Failsafe is not applicable for transient and temporary tables.
5. Failsafe is outside the time-travel boundary and only needed if any there is a disaster, rest all case can be managed by time-travel.
6. Timetravel & failsafe, both incur a cost.

Refer this [link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-editions.html):

[image]